# Why the SelectedItem is not extracted as usual?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

This is my first question in this awesome platform, and yes I had searched here how to do this, which in my case is rare, because it suppose to work, but all I get is nothing from the SelectedItem as a string (its content, which is a TextBlock)

Here is the XAML portion, which is a ListBox with ListItems stack in it:

```
 <Button x:Name="propertyChooser" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="90" Margin="22,379,21,0"  OpacityMask="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="" Foreground="Black" Click="propertyChooser_Click" >
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/AminoBlocks;component/Images/fillblock.png" />
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Popup x:Name="PropertyPopUp" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="400" Width="400" IsOpen="False" >
                <!--ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScrollViewer1" Height="620" Width="400"-->
                <Grid Height="400" Width="400" Background="White">
                <ListBox x:Name="propertyPicker" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Height="400" Width="400" SelectionChanged="propertyPicker_SelectionChanged">

                    <ListBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="property1"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" Height="45" Width="450" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Non-polar, aliphatic" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <!--Click="property1_Click"-->


                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="property2"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" Height="45" Width="450" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Non-polar, aromatic" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <!--Click="property1_Click"-->


                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                   ...
```

Ok, the list is 9 items long, and when you click the button the list shows up as a pop up, then you press or select the property and the code behind, it suppose to change the button content to the property selected in the ListBox. So far I found how to do that, but I get empty or null or the type of the content which is the type of the selectedItem, the type of the listbox item. All I want is the Text of the TextBlock that is in the ListBoxItem I select from the ListBox.

The code behind for this even is:

```
    private void propertyPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem selected = propertyPicker.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem; //Selected item.
        string selectedText = selected.Content as String; //Content of the Item.

        if (propertyPicker.SelectedItem != null)
            propertyChooser.Content = selectedText; //(propertyPicker.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content as string;

        PropertyPopUp.IsOpen = false; //When the item get selected, close the pop up.

    }
                                 ...
```

Yes, this suppose to do the job, but it doesn't, as I said above, it just get me a empty, null or the type of the selectedItem, the type of the listboxitem... I tried the long way, the one that is being implemented and the short way, the one that is commented at the side.

Why wont the SelectedItem, it's content wouldn't pass as it is, a Text from a TextBlock, which is what the ListBox has in it as ListBoxItem ?

Thanks to anyone who answer my noob question, and pardon me if I make a mistake when posting this or one when coding, which I don't quite seem to get, since I am asking here and since must be a logic or some other kind of error my sight doesn't see.

fr33

Answer (score 2):

The contents of your ListBox are TextBlocks. Try casting your SelectedItem to a TextBlock then get your text from it.

Comment: @fr33 No genius just been there before. If the answer worked please accept

Answer (score 2):

The content of your selected ListBoxItem is a TextBlock, not a string.  The line

```
string selectedText = selected.Content as String; //Content of the Item.
```

Needs to be:

```
string selectedText = ((TextBlock)selected.Content).Text; //Content of the Item.
```

Comment: Hey thanks man, I already did that with the tip @Mark Hall told me :)